# yuicompressor-maven-plugin not bounded to process-resources

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, yui-compressor

I have been trying to figure out why yuicompressor-maven-plugin is not executed during "mvn package".  I can execute it in an independent task as described in the link below but somehow the plugin does not get called from maven life cycle.

http://davidb.github.com/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_compress.html

and here is the sample pom.xml I use,

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
     <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
         <source>1.6</source>
         <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
     </plugin>

    <!-- yuicompressor-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>compress</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
            <force>true</force>
            <jswarn>false</jswarn>
            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/minified</webappDirectory>
            <aggregations>
              <aggregation>
                    <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js/abc-min.js</output>
                <includes>
                  <include>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js/comments.txt</include>
                  <include>${project.build.directory}/minified/js/def.js</include>
                </includes>
              </aggregation>              
            </aggregations>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>       

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <warSourceExcludes>js/**/*.js,js/**/*.txt,css/**/*.css,css/**/*.txt</warSourceExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>       

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

I have read similar posts but could not figure out why it's not bounded to "process-resources".  Phase and Goal are explicitly set so not sure why it's not called. Is there a way to debug why yuicompressor-maven-plugin is not called during "mvn package"?  I use maven 2.2.1.  Perhaps the version of my Maven won't work with the plugin?

thanks for your help,

syamashi

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to put the running out of the pluginManagement area into the usual plugins area like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
      ....
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

In pluginManagement you define only the default for plugin in particular the verison but you really don't bound to real execution. For other plugins etc. this works cause the are alreay defined in the build area of the supoer pom so this give you the opportunity to redefine them via pluginManagement but not with a plugin which never has been part of any build area.

Comment: Hello khmarbaise,

It worked with setting outside of the pluginManagement area.  Thank you.  Although, I'm still not clear with the usage of when to use pluginManagement and plugins.  How do you tell what plugins are defined in the super pom by default?  So if I want bind plugins or default plugins to a certain phase of the Maven lifecycle, those configuration should go into plugins and not pluginManagement?

Thanks so much for your help!!